# Can I add bold to simple format? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I make the `@request.correspondence` bold or strong?

```
asdf = "------------\r\n\r\n#{Date.today}\r\n\r\nINPUTED BY: #{current_fan.first_name} (INRU)\r\n\r\n" + @request.correspondence + "\n"
```

so when i go

```
<%= simple_format(asdf) %>
```

the `@request.correspondence` is bold?

Comment: Have you tried  `font-weight: bold;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just add `b` tag inside your string:

```rb
my_integer = 10
my_string = "123<b>#{my_integer}</b>\n456"
simple_format(my_string)
# => "<p>123<b>10</b>\n<br />456</p>"
```

It is more more convenient to combine it with `tag` helper:

```rb
my_integer = 10
my_string = "123#{tag.b(my_integer)}\n456"
simple_format(my_string)
# => "<p>123<b>10</b>\n<br />456</p>"
```

You can even wrap all the text in the `b` tag (instead of default `p`) with `:wrapper_tag` option:

```rb
my_string = "123\n456"
simple_format(my_string, {}, wrapper_tag: :b)
# => "<b>123\n<br />456</b>"
```

You can also add class to `simple_format` (you need define it in CSS):

```rb
my_string = "123\n456"
simple_format(my_string, class: "bold-text")
# => "<p class="bold-text">123\n<br />456</p>"
```

As you can see, `<b>` is [one of the safe tags](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah/blob/main/lib/loofah/html5/safelist.rb#L59) that `simple_format` doesn't sanitize, so you can create what you need